# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have this code:

```
msg.author.send(Finished);
```

And it isn't working. Finished is a const variable which is a Discord.MessageEmbed. This issue is very annoying and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.
If you want to see most of the code here it is:

```
client.on('message', msg => {

    if (msg.content === '-na') {
        if (msg.channel === Discord.DMChannel) {
            return
            } else
            if (msg.member.roles.cache.has('756713479003701338')) {
                msg.author.send(Ping);

                msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                    {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                            msg.author.send(Title);
                            EmbedPing = collected.first().content;

                            msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                                {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                                    msg.author.send(Message);
                                    EmbedTitle = collected.first().content;

                                    msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                                        {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                                            msg.author.send(Image);
                                            EmbedMessage = collected.first().content;
                                            
                                            msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                                                {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                                                    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
                                                        msg.author.send(ImageURL);
                                                        EmbedImage = collected.first().content;

                                                        var FinishedEmbedImage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                            .setColor('#FFD700')
                                                            .setTitle(EmbedTitle)
                                                            .setDescription(EmbedMessage)
                                                            .setImage(EmbedImage)
                                                            .setTimestamp()
                                                            .setFooter('Sent By: ' + msg.author)

                                                        allyAnnouncementChannel.send(EmbedPing, FinishedEmbed);

                                                    } else
                                                    msg.author.send(Finished);

                                                    var FinishedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                        .setColor('#FFD700')
                                                        .setTitle(EmbedTitle)
                                                        .setDescription(EmbedMessage)
                                                        .setTimestamp()
                                                        .setFooter('Sent By: ' + msg.author)

                                                    allyAnnouncementChannel.send(EmbedPing, FinishedEmbed);
                                                }).catch(Cancelled)
                                        }).catch(Cancelled)
                                }).catch(Cancelled)
                    }).catch(Cancelled)
        };
    };
});
```

Ping, Title, Message, Image, ImageURL and Finished are all embed variables.
EmbedPing, EmbedTitle, EmbedMessage, and EmbedImage are all empty string variables.

```
const allyAnnouncementChannel = client.channels.cache.get('756701256122236941')
```

Discord is obviously the require function.
client is Discord.Client();.

Comment: The error means that `msg.author` is `undefined`, which shouldn't happen if `msg` is a Discord.js `Message`. Where are you getting `msg` from?

Comment: client.on('message', msg => {
code's in here
})

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but you might want to use [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) instead of nesting your promises like that. Also, to check if a channel is a DM channel, use `msg.channel.type == 'dm'`.